# Database Design - Multiple Category and Multiple Sub Category

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, relational-database

I have a question on how to design for multiple category and multiple sub category. A store will have multiple Categories and multiple sub categories.

For example, Stores will have Women's clothing, Men's Clothing as categories and have Accessories and bottoms as sub categories

If it matters, I'm using SQL Server 2016. These are the tables I have so far:

```
TABLE Store
    StoreID INT
    Description NVARCHAR(500)

TABLE Category
    CategoryID INT
    Description NVARCHAR(500)

TABLE Subcategory
    SubcategoryID INT
    CategoryID INT
    Description NVARCHAR(500)
```

Comment: What if subcategories have subcategories?  You can/should probably treat categories and subcategories as the same thing.

Comment: @Jerrad -  No, just category and sub category. Sub category will not have sub categories.

Comment: Could each store could have different categories and subcategories available?  Store 1 could have cat(A) with Sub of (A1,A2) while store 2 could have cat(A) with sub (A1, A3) [Notice different subs for same cat] and cat (B) with (B1, B2?)  if so I see Store; storeCategory with columns[StoreID, CatID, SubCatID] and FK's to cat and SubCat tables. or just one table cat with two columns and fk's to the same table twice. and a parentID in table; allows for N dimenions but now you have to work with recursive queries or forxml path.

Comment: here's a hint: a subcategory is a category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another table StoreCategories, that will keep the StoreID and CategoryID to allow each Store to have multiple Categories and each Category to have multiple Stores.

Make sure Foreign Keys are properly placed for each tables.
[image: UML Stores/Categories]
Another intermediary table can be placed if a SubCategory can be used on multiple Categories.
Obviously to avoid double SubCategories.

Comment: Does this design also allow for the category to have multiple sub categories?

Comment: It does, each SubCategory has one Category. So the sum of all SubCategories linked to a Category makes the multiplicity.

Comment: Okay, maybe i'm referring to it incorrectly with multiple but each Category will also have multiple Sub Category. Men's Clothing Category will have Sub Categories (Shoes, Accessories, Ties) and Women's Clothing Category will also have Sub Categories (Shoes, Accessories)

Comment: This implementation allows each category to have multiple Sub categories

Comment: You mention "another intermediary table can be placed.." is that not already in the diagram?

Comment: It is not, a table between "Category" and "SubCategory" could be placed to enhance multiplicity. We are on a 1->n multiplicity, with an intermediary table we could have a n->n multiplicity, this could be used to avoid multiplying the same SubCategory if it is in multiple Categories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any value to having separate Category and SubCategory tables.  Just have a single Category table, with a nullable `ParentCategory` column.

```
TABLE Category      
  CategoryID INT
  ParentCategory INT
  Description NVARCHAR(500)
```

Your top-level categories will be the ones with `null` for ParentCategory.

You say that there will not be multiple levels of subcategories now, but requirements like that have a tendency to change down the road.  If you do end up needing sub-sub-categories at some point, you won't have to rewrite a bunch of queries with a design like this.

Then you will need a table to store the categories for the stores:

```
TABLE StoreCategory
  StoreID INT
  CategoryID INT
```

Comment: There is one, if you wish not SubCategories to be linked with a Store directly but only through a Category.

Comment: That could be enforced using triggers.

Comment: Yes but triggers are performance consuming, but I admit your call is good it will reduce the technological debt you have to the design.

Comment: I don't imagine there will be so many categories (or that they will be updated so frequently) that trigger performance will be an issue.

Comment: That mainly depends of the business involved here.

Comment: It would be a pretty confusing store if the categories were changing fast enough for trigger performance to be noticeable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142619/discussion-between-hybris95-and-jerrad).